# Circular Import - Django

Tags: django

I can't see where the circular import is

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '<module 'Reciept.urls' from 'Reciept\urls.py'>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see the 'urlpatterns' variable with valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import

project level urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('PPMS/', include('PPMS.urls')),
    path('Dispute/',include('Dispute.urls')),
    path('Reciept/', include('Reciept.urls'))
]
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import Disputeindex

app_name='Dispute'

urlpatterns = [
    path('',Disputeindex, name='Disputeindex')
]
```

View.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def Recipetindex(request):

    return render(request, 'Reciept/index.html')
```

Comment: I've created a project with the scenario you have mentioned and it worked correctly.